# Is "call in a taxi" correct?

Tags: phrase-request, idiomatic-language

Is "call in a taxi" correct? I thought "call in a taxi" was correct, because you would say "call in a supply package", but after looking up Google, I barely get any results telling me that it's not idiomatic. What's the correct phrasal verb I should use?

For example:

> I wanted to call in a taxi after I got out of the restaurant.

Comment: What type of situation are you referring to? When you are on the street and want a taxi to stop so you can get it, or using a phone to schedule a taxi to pick you up?

Comment: The phrase *call in* is usually reserved for calling for help. As in, *calling in the troops to rescue you*. You wouldn't normally use it with a taxi—unless, perhaps, you really needed to escape from a bad situation and only a taxi could get you out. With a taxi you would normally just say *I wanted to call a taxi* or possibly *I wanted to call **for** a taxi.* But not *call* ***in***.

Comment: It *might* be used in this sense: `I wanted to call in a taxi, but my cell phone wouldn't work in the cab`.